# Angular 5, URLSearchParams in IE11

Tags: angular

In my angular 5 application I have this following error:

> Http error: {"description":"'URLSearchParams' non è
>   definito","number":-2146823279,"stack":"ReferenceError:
>   'URLSearchParams' non è definito

URLSearchParams is not supported by IE11 so are there any kind of imports maybe in `polyfills.ts` to make it works?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

use [URLSearchParams Polyfill](https://github.com/jerrybendy/url-search-params-polyfill)

```
npm install url-search-params-polyfill --save
```

and import it in your polyfills.ts

```
import 'url-search-params-polyfill';
```

or to webpack config

```
entry: {
 bundle: [
  'url-search-params-polyfill',
  ...
 ]
}
```

Comment: after doing this and when start project always give me this errors : ' Cannot find module 'rxjs'.  
'Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'EventEmitter<{}>'.
'Cannot find module 'rxjs/operators'